# Selecting a specific row entry in excel and printing the entire row if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, excel

I have csv file in excel that looks like this (sorry cant place pictures in the post yet)

[RAW DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQujx.png)

Here is what i want to do:

1) I want python to read through column B and find the phrase RCOM (highlighted)

2) Once it find that phrase, i want it to show me the date entry and the corresponding amounts which i have made bold and are in the red color.

3) hopefully making it read something like this:

```
30-08-2018 273585.8
27-09-2018 275701.4
25-10-2018 276780
```

*If possible putting the entries on seperate lines would be great, but if not thats fine too.

4) I will then store these in a variable of my choice and print it out as needed.

I know the column where the word RCOM is located, and i know the column where the amounts i want are located (B and K respectively)

I am very new to coding, any help will be appreciated. Im just trying to automate the boring stuff :) 
Thanks

Comment: It's customary to show what you've tried so far. (So it doesn't look like you're asking people to solve the problem _for_ you...)

Comment: oh my bad. im still learning about this..but the things i tried were to first convert the csv to excel, because i found another snippet of a code on stackoverflow which said i could extract atleast the row numbers into a text file. Unfortunately that only worked on xlsx files and not csv..but i gave up on that and then tried to copy the data to a text file and see if i could read that data, and i couldnt work with that either..i dont really have the attempts saved anywhere to show here..but i swear i didnt want anyone to solve it for me. a nudge in the right direction is enough,ill do the rest

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a data frame using read_csv function from pandas library. Once you have the data in data frame format, you can reach to data mentioned in your question by filtering the data according your requirements. I know this answer is very generic and does not provide a code suggestion but I believe that all information you need can be found in following page https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

For importing data Getting Data In/Out section will be helpful and for filtering (masking) the data Selection section will help.